# Build springboot for cordapp - javax.Json not found exception

Tags: corda

I am writing a springboot to integrate with cordaapp and building with gradle. I want to call CordaRPC in springboot. Though i am able to build i am getting this below error always,

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.json.JsonValue
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at net.corda.nodeapi.ArtemisTcpTransport$Companion.tcpTransport(ArtemisTcpTransport.kt:84)
        at net.corda.nodeapi.ArtemisTcpTransport$Companion.tcpTransport$default(ArtemisTcpTransport.kt:44)
        at net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCClient.<init>(CordaRPCClient.kt:108)
        at net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCClient.<init>(CordaRPCClient.kt:83)
        at net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCClient.<init>(CordaRPCClient.kt:83)
        at net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCClient.<init>(CordaRPCClient.kt)
```

for the line,

```
CordaRPCClient rpcClient = new CordaRPCClient(rpcAddress);
```

Snippet of my build.gradle file,

```
... apply plugin: 'java' apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot' apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management' apply plugin: 'net.corda.plugins.cordapp' apply plugin: 'net.corda.plugins.cordformation' apply plugin: 'net.corda.plugins.quasar-utils' ... dependencies {

    testCompile "junit:junit:$junit_version"

    // Corda integration dependencies
    cordaCompile "$corda_release_group:corda-core:$corda_release_version"
    cordaCompile "$corda_release_group:corda-finance:$corda_release_version"
    cordaCompile "$corda_release_group:corda-jackson:$corda_release_version"
    cordaCompile "$corda_release_group:corda-rpc:$corda_release_version"
    cordaCompile "$corda_release_group:corda-webserver-impl:$corda_release_version"
    cordaRuntime "$corda_release_group:corda:$corda_release_version"
    cordaRuntime "$corda_release_group:corda-webserver:$corda_release_version"

    testCompile "$corda_release_group:corda-node-driver:$corda_release_version"

    // CorDapp dependencies
    // Specify your cordapp's dependencies below, including dependent CorDapps
    cordapp "$corda_release_group:corda-finance:$corda_release_version"

    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.11.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.11.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-slf4j-impl', version: '2.11.0'

//    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa' //    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey'
    implementation ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web', {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'logback-classic'
    }
    )
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

    implementation files('<path to my cordapp jar>')

} ...
```

Comment: try with add javax.json-api dependency

Comment: this simply worked!!!! thanks. i was thinking including corda should have brought all the required dependencies.

Comment: Not only is that the wrong solution, it is also the wrong dependency from the original corda dependency tree

Answer (score 1):

Add the dependency

`group='javax.json', module='javax.json-api', version='1.1.4'`

Answer (score 1):

The actual issue is `apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'`.

This is bumping `org.apache.activemq:artemis-core-client` from `2.6.2` to `2.6.4` which is where the `org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-json_1.0_spec:1.0-alpha-1` goes missing.

If you remove the spring plugin everything will work again.

Despite what is generated by Spring Initializr, you only need

```
apply plugin: 'java' 
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
```

and you can safely remove `apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'`